# Silverlight ListBox Grouping using MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

```
<ListBox Name="lstNorthwind" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>                            
                            <TextBlock Name="txtCountry" Text="{Binding country}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

In my database table i have fileds like fname, so i want grouping of all fname according to country. And please tell me what is static source and relative source.

Answer (score 0):

To group or order your data i'm think you can use [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx). Its very easy to  understand and perfect to use with MVVM.

About the concepts you asked you can find them all in microsoft site:

[Relative Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[Static Resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx)